# Preventing file fownload (any file even css and js) in IIS8

Tags: iis, iis-8

Is there any way to set up IIS in a way that no file can be downloaded? (without xml configuration and using the IIS UI only).

I know I can remove all mime-types but that is inconvenient, I'm looking for a better option.

Comment: Place it somewhere on the server that is not accessible from the web (eg, exists outside of any web-roots).

Comment: I already know about this, looking for an IIS solution.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot stop of css or js as the server cannot differentiate between a normal
>   request and a download request when it comes to css or js.

Say you have a CSS or js included in your webpage any html page .This css file will need to be downloaded by the browser.So at server side(IIS) you cannot differentiate a normal download request or browser request. You can deny the download request if the referrer is not matching.For example if someone take sthe URL and directly copying and pasting it in another browser,the referrer header will not be present.Similarly if someone else hotlink to your resources(css,js files),you can stop that too.

> By [deny download based on Referrer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdevelopertips/2008/12/15/tip-34-did-you-know-how-to-stop-hot-linking-from-your-site-using-url-rewrite-in-iis-7-0/)   using URLRewrite